# OSX Snow Leopard: Static and dynamic link behaving differently

Tags: macos, linker, g++, osx-snow-leopard

I have some code structured like this:

Fixed mainline -> user code -> dependent library

These three parts can be statically linked and all is well.
Alternatively, the mainline can be turned into an executable
and the user code into a dylib, and the mainline loads the
user code with dlopen() and enters it with dlsym().

I have hundreds of test programs where this works fine, but two cases
where it fails:

- Case 1: the dependent library is gmpxx (which depends on gmp).
- Case 2: the dependent library is SDL

In the gmp case the dynamic program prints the correct answers by then terminates with:

```
  flx_run(29601) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff712ac500: pointer being freed was not allocated
  *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
  Abort trap

  (gdb) bt
  #0  0x00007fff8438e0b6 in __kill ()
  #1  0x00007fff8442e9f6 in abort ()
  #2  0x00007fff84346195 in free ()
  #3  0x00000001000d3a35 in flxusr::gmp__hyphen_0::_init_ ()
  Previous frame inner to this frame (gdb could not unwind past this frame)
```

I would guess some memory corruption is here.

In the SDL case:

```
  ~/felix>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=build/release/lib/rtl build/release/bin/flx_arun  demos/sdl/sdl-1.01.03-0.dylib
  frames in  seconds =  FPS
  frames in  seconds =  FPS
  frames in  seconds =  FPS
```

whereas

```
  ~/felix>demos/sdl/sdl-1.01.03-0
  98 frames in 5.016 seconds = 19.5375 FPS
  100 frames in 5.043 seconds = 19.8295 FPS
  82 frames in 5.043 seconds = 16.2602 FPS
```

The frame rate data is formatted by

```
   _urv20946  = ::flx::rtl::strutil::str(((double)PTF Frames  / seconds ));
```

where

```
  template<class T>
  string str(T const &t) {
    std::ostringstream x;
    x << t;
    return x.str();
  }
```

noting this code is "in" a dependent library (well of course not, it is in a header file!)

Any ideas?